# C# log soap envelope

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I have a console application that makes requests to a third party web service. It looks like the service is having some issues and their support asked me to log the soap envelope and send it to them so that they can investigate. How do I do that?
I tried adding this to the app.config but I don't get the `<soapenv:Envelope ....</soapenv:Envelope>` tags.

```
<system.diagnostics>
<trace autoflush="true"/>
<sources>
  <source name="System.Net" maxdatasize="52428800" tracemode="protocolonly">
    <listeners>
      <add name="TraceFile"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.Net.Sockets" maxdatasize="52428800" tracemode="protocolonly">
    <listeners>
      <add name="TraceFile"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.Net.Cache" maxdatasize="52428800" tracemode="protocolonly">
    <listeners>
      <add name="TraceFile"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.Net.HttpListener" maxdatasize="52428800" tracemode="protocolonly">
    <listeners>
      <add name="TraceFile"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<sharedListeners>
  <add name="TraceFile" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
    initializeData="trace.log"/>
</sharedListeners>
<switches>
  <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose" />
  <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose" />
</switches>
```

Comment: Check trace.log file using traceviewr utility and send the log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to export the soap envelope using the instructions on this page: [Logging an Xml SOAP Request from a C# client before sending it](https://www.rhyous.com/2015/04/30/logging-an-xml-soap-request-from-a-c-client-before-sending-it/)

Answer (score -1):

Use Fiddler. Its Freeware and very helpfull to track any kind of webtraffic http://www.telerik.com/fiddler